# How do I do multi-domain https with mod_wsgi?

Tags: django, apache, https, mod-wsgi

I'm a developer and a bit of an apache novice and I'm trying to transition a bunch of our Django https servers to mod_wsgi, which previously used mod_python:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName *.example.com

    SSLEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/star_example_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/star_example_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/DigiCertCA.crt

    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0

    <Directory "/var/www/foo.example.com">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.foo.settings
        PythonPath "['/home/django'] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug on
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/bar.example.com">
        SetHandler python-program
        PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
        SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE example.bar.settings
        PythonPath "['/home/django'] + sys.path"
        PythonDebug on
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This allows us to run several https sites on the same physical server (ip). Adding a new https host simply involves adding a new `<Directory>` section, and creating the corresponding directory under `/var/www/`.

The closest I've gotten is by using

```
<Directory "/var/www/bar.example.com">
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

and creating `/var/www/bar.example.com/bar.wsgi`, then I can access urls like `https://bar.example.com/bar.wsgi/...rest..of..path..`

I haven't been able to find a directive (that can be used inside `<Directory>`) that is equivalent to `WSGIScriptAlias` when the target is a *file-path*, like we're using for the non-https sites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/venv/upgrade/example/bar/bar.wsgi
    <Directory "/var/www/bar/">
        Order deny,allow
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Which allows us to go to `http://bar.example.com/...rest..of..path..` (ie. no `bar.wsgi` prefix).

Is it possible to get rid of the `bar.wsgi` part in the https url?

**[Solution:]** (based on @GrahamDumpleton's link):

```
<Directory /var/www/bar.example.com/>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

works beautifully.

Comment: I don't follow completely, but isn't this what VirtualHosts are for?

Comment: That's what you use VirtualHosts for on non-https setups, yes, but that doesn't work for https since the SSL handshake happens before the server sees the HTTP/1.1 Host header (and thus doesn't know which certificate to present).

Comment: Which is why for SSL you should have unique IPs for SSL site.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton that's too old-fashioned -- besides being impractical (and why wildcard certificates exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

See the bit towards the end of the section where shows use of mod_rewrite and an application wrapper to do fixups of SCRIPT_NAME.